# java - useBean in jsp and getAttribute in jsp but NULL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, usebean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jsp useBean is NUll by getAttribute by servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027160/jsp-usebean-is-null-by-getattribute-by-servlet)

user is null in servlet.
Pls let me if doing mistake.

i m trying to get all html element in bean
rateCode.jsp

```
**<%@page import="com.hermes.data.RateCode_" %>**
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rate Code</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
         **<jsp:useBean id="user" class="com.hermes.data.RateCode_" scope="session" >
            <jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/></jsp:useBean>**
            <form  id="f_rateCode" action="/ratePromoCodes" method="post"  >
                <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="header">Rate Code Administrations</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" style="border-style: solid;">Rate Code:</td>
                        <td align="left" style="border-style: solid;">
                            <input type="text" id="code" name="code" value="${user.code}"  size="10" maxlength="32" style="width: 100px"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right" style="border-style: solid;">Rate Description:</td>
                    <td align="left" style="border-style: solid;">
                        <input type="text" id="description" name="description" value="<%=user.getDescription()%>" maxlength="128" size="40"></td>
                </tr>              
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="ok" /></td> </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Servlet - ratePromoCodes

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        RateCode_ rc = (RateCode_) req.getAttribute("user");
        Enumeration an = req.getAttributeNames();
        Enumeration pn = req.getParameterNames();
        Object o = null;
        while (an.hasMoreElements()) {
            o = an.nextElement();
            System.out.println(o);
        }
        while (pn.hasMoreElements()) {
            o = pn.nextElement();
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
```

RateCode.java (javaBean)

```
public class RateCode_  {    
    private String code ;
    private String description;
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```