# Using beans in servlets

Tags: servlets, javabeans

I has a jsp page (index.jsp) with a form with two text fileds username and password like.

```
 <form action="MyClass">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

On form submition i am invocking a servlet. I know that we can get the entered username and password values by using request methods,

```
  request.getParameter("username");
  request.getParameter("password");
```

But i don't want to use them , instead i want to store these values in a bean called BeanClass and i want to retrieve values from the bean in the sevlet. How can i get it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `<jsp:useBean/>` action to instantiate the `BeanClass` with `request` or `session` scope in [JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro11.html).

Sample - EmpServlet.java

```
package com.me;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class EmpServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
         Emp emp=(Emp)request.getAttribute("emp");
         pw.print(emp);
    }
}
```

Emp.java : Emp bean

```
package com.me;
public class Emp {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    public Emp() {
        name="";
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean valid()
    {
        return age!=0 && name.length()!=0;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Emp{" + "age=" + age + ", name=" + name + '}';
    }
}
```

emp.jsp (view)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib  prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<jsp:useBean id="emp" class="com.me.Emp" scope="request">
    <jsp:setProperty name="emp" property="*"/>
</jsp:useBean>

<c:if test="${emp.valid()}">
    <jsp:forward page="emp"/>
</c:if>
<form method="post" action="emp.jsp">
    <br/><input type="text" name="age"/>
    <br/><input type="text" name="name"/>
    <br/><input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EmpServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.me.EmpServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EmpServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/emp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: can i use this statement in index.jsp it self.. If so where to place this statement in jsp page.. and i also tried to get the valeus using getter methods from servlet but iam getting null values

Answer (score 1):

To the point, you're looking for a MVC framework like [JSF](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html) or [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html). With JSF it'll look something like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.username}" required="true" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{bean.password}" required="true" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void submit() {
        // Do here your job.
    }

    // Add/generate getters and setters.
}
```

That's all. No need for a servlet.

If you really want to do it the low level servlet way, you'd need to populate the bean yourself. This can be convenienced with [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils) to save boilerplate code.

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
BeanUtils.populate(bean, request.getParameterMap());
request.setAttribute("bean", bean);
// ...
```

The `<jsp:useBean>` does not allow for the MVC approach, it's more a MV. You have to mingle the conversion/validation into model and control the request/response inside the view, tasks which a controller should do. MVC frameworks offer you a controller which takes all this nasty boilerplate tasks from your hands.